# Folders.Item(FolderName).Folders : Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptions: The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found

Tags: vba, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm very new in vb.net and outlook add-in, working on a project to build an outlook add-in (VSTO using VisualStudio 2017) where I'me getting this error for which im not getting any clue even after hours of googling, may be im not in the right direction. Thats why Im here to ask for your assistance. Thanks

Here is the error I've got, and I've pointed the line in the code where the error appears.

**Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptions: The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.**

**Update:**

I was testing a little bit and found the if I don't rename the root folder problematically  in this line `dFolder.Name = "X" + dName` , `dName = dFolder.Name` rather rename name manually within outlook add data file section then the full function works fine without any error.

**Note:** the purpose of this code is to copy emails from one folder to another where both root folder name is same because the destination folder is just a mirror copy of source folder And for this emails were not copying if the both folder name is same, That's why I had to rename the destination folder when i'm adding to Store Session so that system can identify the source and destination folder as two different location. I don't know why its not getting the rename value in  `dFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(dName).Folders` . please help.

**.**

```
Public Shared Sub SetSrcAndDst(Src As String, Dst As String)
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNspace As Outlook.NameSpace

    Dim sFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim sFolder As Outlook.Folder

    oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    oNspace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    sFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(Src).Folders

    Dim oStores As Outlook.Stores
    Dim oStore As Outlook.Store

    Dim dPath As String
    Dim dName As String

    Dim dFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim dFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    oStores = oApp.Session.Stores
    oNspace.AddStore(Dst)
    dName = ""

    For Each oStore In oStores
        dFolder = oStore.GetRootFolder
        dPath = oStore.FilePath
        If dPath = Dst Then
            dName = dFolder.FolderPath
            dName = dName.TrimStart({"\"c})
            dFolder.Name = "X" + dName
            dName = dFolder.Name
        End If
    Next


    '''
    ''' Getting error in this below line (dFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(dName).Folders)
    ''' System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExceptions: 
    ''' The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.
    '''

    dFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(dName).Folders

    For Each sFolder In sFolders
        For Each dFolder In dFolders
            If sFolder.Name = dFolder.Name Then
                Call CopyMail(sFolder, dFolder)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

**($exception).StackTrace**

```
 at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.FoldersClass.get_Item(Object Index)
 at AutoBackup.ThisAddIn.SetSrcAndDst(String Src, String Dst) in E:\AutoBackup\ThisAddIn.vb:line 56
 at AutoBackup.SettingsForm.PstConfirmBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\AutoBackup\SettingsForm.vb:line 37
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Please don't tag VB.NET code with VBA. VB.NET has nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: Click "View Details" and paste the stack trace into your post. It's going to be more helpful than that screenshot.

Comment: In all likelihood, `dName` is referring to a non-existing folder.

Comment: its the same without declaring empty string, it gives same error

Answer (score 1):

The error is very unambiguous - the folder with the given name does not exist.

As a test, loop through all root folders to make sure the folder with the given name is really there:

```
for each vFolder in oNspace.Folders
  MsgBox fFolder.Name
next
```

Comment: I was testing a little bit and found the if I don't rename the root folder problematically  in this line `dFolder.Name = "X" + dName` , `dName = dFolder.Name` rather rename name manually within outlook add data file section then the full function works fine without any error.

Comment: **Note: the purpose of this code** is to copy emails from one folder to another where both root folder name is same because the destination folder is just a mirror copy of source folder And for this emails were not copying if the both folder name is same, That's why I had to rename the destination folder when i'm adding to Store Session so that system can identify the source and destination folder as two different location. I don't know why its not getting the rename value in  `dFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(dName).Folders` . please help.

Comment: So what is your current issue?

Comment: Whenever I add some string to rename the Root Folder/PST to differentiate the same name like work.pst and work_backup.pst it doesn't take the value to declare the objFolders like this `dFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(work_backup).Folders` and gives error `An object could not be found.`

Comment: How exactly are you renaming the folder? You are accessing the root folder, which has the name of the store. Did you rename the store? Post screenshots

Comment: I think I may have renamed the store as you said, if you can check the code in this post, please look for 

    `oStores = oApp.Session.Stores
      oNspace.AddStore(Dst)
       dName = ""

       For Each oStore In oStores
          dFolder = oStore.GetRootFolder
          dPath = oStore.FilePath
          If dPath = Dst Then
              dName = dFolder.FolderPath
              dName = dName.TrimStart({"\"c})
              dFolder.Name = "X" + dName
              dName = dFolder.Name
          End If
       Next`

Comment: Here I've added an external pst `oNspace.AddStore(Dst)` then trying to rename ( `dFolder.Name = "X" + dName` ) the Root Folder path (data file name shown in left side bar in outlook)

Comment: You need to change Store.DisplayName., but it is read-only in the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153158/discussion-between-hayat-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Comment: As you said `Store.DisplayName`  is read only,  how do I copy emails from one store to another store where both have the same name, (assuming that as outlook allows it to add multiple store with exact same name)

Comment: I can only suggest using Redemption - it exposes RDOSession.Stores.AddPstStore that returns an RDOPSTStore object: no need to search for it by name.